# If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[R,\infty)$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: [0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[R,\infty)$ for some $R>0$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

Well, my basic idea is since $f$ is continuous, so it is uniform continuous on $[0,R]$ and given it is uniform continuous on $[R,\infty)$, I can take minimum of those two $\delta_1,\delta_2$. But I got stuck when $x$ and $y$ do not belong to same interval,vany hint?

Comment: Use $[0,R+1]$ instead of $[0,R]$ and restrict to $\delta < 1$ when searching for $\delta$

Comment: Could you tell me why [0,R＋1] instead of [0,R]? What is the motivation? what is wrong with the latter choice of compact set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty]$and hence it is uniformly continuous on any compact set. So take your compact set to be $[0,R+1]$. And it is already given to be uniformly continuous on $[R,\infty]$.

$\bf{Edit :}$

For Uniform continuity you need that for $\epsilon>0$ $\exists \ \delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-y|<\delta \implies\ |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Now for the interval $[0,R+1]$ $f$ is uniformly continuous and hence you get, say $\delta_1$. It's given that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[R, \infty)$ so you get say $\delta_2$. Now take your $\delta=\ min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.

My Suggestion :- Draw some pictures to understand whatever I am saying.

Comment: @Thomas  still not getting .please explain a more

Comment: @Eklavya see my edit.

Comment: Could you tell me why you choose compact set $[0, R＋1］$, not $[0,R]$? What is the motivation?